# Error in is.data.frame(x) : 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Tags: r, function, vector, statistics, computer-science

I wrote this function to find correlation between 2 variables in variables of Var1-Var8. But when I run this function it gives me this error and I dont know what to do to solve this issue. I'm new at R programming so if you answer more detailed I will be pleased. Thank you already.

```
findCorrelation=function(df){

  print("which variables do you want to see the Correlation between ?")
  x=readline("Enter the first variable :")
  y=readline("Enter the second variable :")

  cp = sum((df[x] * df[y]),na.rm=T) - (sum(df[x],na.rm=T)*sum(df[y],na.rm=T)/length(df[y]))
  covariance=cp/99


  correlation=covariance/(sd(df[x],na.rm = T)*sd(df[y],na.rm=T))

  print(paste("Correlation betwen variable ",x,"and variable",y,"is",correlation))

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The difference between bracket \[ \] and double bracket \[\[ \]\] for accessing the elements of a list or dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-el)

Comment: You used the wrong kind of brackets.

Answer (score 1):

that has something to do with referencing items in a data frame. A single bracket `df[x]` returns a list. `df[[x]]` returns an atomic vector of doubles. Some functions cannot operate on lists, only on atomic vectors.

Change the statement to this:

`correlation <- covariance/(sd(df[[x]],na.rm = T)*sd(df[[y]],na.rm=T))`

and it should work. Hope this helps!